# How to have comments on same post page? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, css, html, wordpress

I'm using the theme twenty fifteen as a base. I want it so that when a user clicks on comments, it opens in the same page, or in others word, transition when opened instead of having to go to a new link, because it removes the purpose of the original design if I cannot do this. Can someone give me a quick guide on where to fix that? Thanks!

*Theres no code to fix or anything, just plain twenty fifteen I want to move around.*

Comment: have you tried searching for a solution on your own?

Comment: Yes I have, the closest solution I have found was not what I was looking for and all of them are from 10+ years ago.

Comment: First if you are at listing page then its an automatic feature of wordpress that it will open in a new link or in a new tab, secondly if you are at post detail page then it will show only in the same page of your post. if you want to have comments at the listing of the post then you need little customization and some jquery is required in sense to achieve your requirement.